# How to use if else statement ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 4 radiobutton r1,r2,r3,r4. And a date input "tanggal".

in my table i have data in row tanggal `11/15/2018, 11/15/2018, 11/15/2018 11/15/2018`

row waktu`09.00, 09.20, 09.40, and 10.00`

with this query I just can disable one radio button `r1` when I choose a date `11/15/2018` with value in my database

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#tanggal').change(function(){
  var tanggalfromfield = $('#tanggal').val();
  $.ajax({        // Memulai ajax
    method: "POST",      
    url: "ajaxtanggal.php",  
    data: {tanggal: tanggalfromfield}   
  })
  .done(function(hasilajax) {
        $('#nama').val(hasilajax);
        var tam=hasilajax;
        if(tam=='09.00WIB'){
            document.getElementById("r1").disabled = true;
        }
    });

 })
});
</script>
```

when i try to use if else statement nothing change and it's not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#tanggal').change(function(){
  var tanggalfromfield = $('#tanggal').val();  // AMBIL isi dari fiel NPM masukkan variabel 'npmfromfield'
  $.ajax({        // Memulai ajax
    method: "POST",      
    url: "ajaxtanggal.php",    // file PHP yang akan merespon ajax
    data: {tanggal: tanggalfromfield}   // data POST yang akan dikirim
  })
  .done(function(hasilajax) {
        $('#nama').val(hasilajax);
        var tam=hasilajax;
        if(tam=='09.00WIB'){
            document.getElementById("r1").disabled = true;
        }else if(tam=='09.20WIB'){
            document.getElementById("r2").disabled = true;
        }else if(tam=='09.40WIB'){
            document.getElementById("r3").disabled = true;
        }
    });

 })
});
</script>
```

How to disable r2,r3,r4 when I choose date `11/15/2018`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make standart debugging actions:

1) check *tam=='09.00WIB* - is this still works? According to code - must be.

2) use

```
$('#nama').val(hasilajax);
var tam=hasilajax;
console.log('tam:'); console.log(tam);
```

to see real value of tam. It can be surprisingly not what you expect.

3) add message in various statement to check if it is goes here:

```
    if(tam=='09.00WIB'){
        document.getElementById("r1").disabled = true;
        console.log('r1 - worked');
    }else if(tam=='09.20WIB'){
        document.getElementById("r2").disabled = true;
        console.log('r2 - worked');
    }else if(tam=='09.40WIB'){
        document.getElementById("r3").disabled = true;
        console.log('r3 - worked');
    } else {
        console.log('nothing of this');
    }
```

Only then you can understand where is error. Probably not in "*if else if*"